# Minimising the area of triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, triangles, area

Triangle $ABC$ has coordinate $A(2,1)$.

$B$ passes through the line $x=y$.

$C$ passes through the line $y=0$.

What is the minimum possible area of the triangle and what are its coordinates?

My attempt :

Let the coordinates be $A(2,1)$, $B(y, y)$, $C(x, 0)$.

Calculating the area it turns out to be

$\frac{1}{2}|{x+y-xy}|$.

Now I know that if we take the derivative and equate it to 0 then we can proceed further, but I can't find a way to relate x and y.
I used that the sum of two sides is always greater than the third side but it was of no use.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed further. Thanks in advance!

Edit :
The points are only integral

They are not on the same line.

Sorry, to those who have answered the question already, for missing out this information.

Comment: I found $x=y=1$.

Comment: Can you please tell how. Can we differentiate two variables while treating other as constant?If I differentiate with respect to x, treating y as constant,I get y=1. But how will we get x then and more importantly is it correct?

Comment: For those who have downvoted the question, can you please mention the problem that the question has, so it may be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your work
Area$= \dfrac12 |x+y-xy|$

> $= \dfrac12 |1-(x-1)(y-1)|$

Since $x,$$y$ are integers
$(x-1)(y-1)$ $= K $
Where $K$ is a integer,
Therefore
Minumum of $|1-K|$ will be $1$.
Thus minimum Area $= 0.5$

Note that infinite triangles following the given conditions are possible with area $0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following :

For the choice $x=0$ and $y=\epsilon$ , an arbitrarily small positive real number, the area can be made arbitrarily small.

Hence the minimal possible area of the triangle doesn't exist.

Suggestion : In case you consider only integral points, try computing the area considering few nearby points of $(2,1)$.

It won't be a difficult exercise.

Comment: Is this the case even if I define that the coordinates are integral? (I haven't mentioned it in the question)

Comment: Then the situation will be surely different.

Comment: Sorry for missing out on the information

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes that's is not much difficult but in olympiads, we don't get much time so as to compute area by this method.

Answer (score 0):

Take $B(3,3)$ and $C(0,-3)$.

We see that $A,$ $B$ and $C$ are placed on the same line.

Id est, the minimum does not exist and the infimum is equal to $0$.

Comment: Sorry for missing out information, the coordinates have to form a 'real triangle'.

Comment: @Satwik Yes, of course. I showed that for any such triangle the area can be closed to $0$. Since a minimal positive number does not exist, we got that a minimal area does not exist.

Comment: Yes that is true if we take coordinates as any real number. Since your answer, I have changed the question to that the coordinates must be integral and not lying on the same line.